# CloudWatch - Delete logs after transfered

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a CloudWatch set up on my EC2 instance to transfer logs to specific log groups.

In time, those logs can grow quite big in size so I wanted to delete them for example, on weekly basis.

I was wondering if there is any option of setting up auto-cleanup from EC2 instance, of transferred logs using Cloudwatch?

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want to clean up the files on EC2, or the logs stored in CloudWatch? If the former, what is the OS that you're using?

Comment: @Parsifal On EC2, amzn2-ami.

Comment: How did it go with the issue? Any progress or still fully unresolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the logfiles from EC2 running Linux, you have two choices:

1. If you're using logfiles that already rotate based on time or other value, you can use the `auto_removal` option to delete them after the log agent is finished. See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection).
2. If you're using a file that's constantly updated, you'll need to use `logrotate`, which is a program invoked by CRON that will rename, compress, and delete old files. There's a good intro doc [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04).

If you use `logrotate`, here's an example config that I've found useful for high-volume log sources. It performs a rotate if the file reaches 100 megabytes, rather than just doing it every day (you'll need to run it from `cron.hourly` to make that useful). Most important, it enables `copytruncate`, which will truncate the file in-place, allowing the program to continue writing to it.

```
/var/log/filename.log {
  rotate 7
  daily
  maxsize 100M
  nodateext
  missingok
  notifempty
  copytruncate
  compress
  delaycompress
}
```